# Let's expel [native]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[native](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/native) is undefined and has 12 questions, pretty much each about something different.  Does anyone object to nuking this tag?

Comment: Man, that title could have gone in a much darker direction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the classic meta tag. It should go. I've started trickle editing them.

Annd gone

Comment: Time for more coffee?  http://superuser.com/questions/232235/howto-boot-directly-into-a-virtualbox-image  :-)

Comment: ._. This is not the groggy mod you are looking for. Move along.

Comment: Ok, THAT was wierd. It deleted native again. Blew away the tags, manually changed it to virtualbox. What the whaaaaaat?